# jquery dataTables - how to extract row data onclick event

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, datatables

I'm trying to familiarize myself with the jquery dataTables plug in: http://www.datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters

**What's Working**

I have json data being returned from the server to my client and the table is being populated.

**What's Not working**

I need to be able to capture the data in a given row, when the row is selected / clicked on by the end user.

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/1515/

```
$("#users tr").click(function(){
  alert($(this).find("pID").val());
   });
```

The above javascript is what I've been playing around with.  Trouble is that the ajax call happens automagically and I'm not the one creating the rows in the table. Ultimately, I need to be able to grab some of the fields in each row, in addition to the ID / pID

**What I've tried so far**

Besides the playing with the javascript code, I've also been reviewing this: http://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html
But in that example, all the data is defined client side, so it makes it easy to specify either an id or a class for each table row

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 20):

Hope this is what you r looking for

**Html**

```
<table id="users" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th id="pID">ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Available</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1-1</td>
            <td>1-2</td>
            <td>1-3</td>
            <td>1-4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2-1</td>
            <td>2-2</td>
            <td>2-3</td>
            <td>2-4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Available</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
    var table = $('#users').DataTable();
    $('#users tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        console.log(table.row(this).data());
    });
});
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/1518/)

Comment: Glad it helped you :)

Comment: @Matthias check the browser console for the result/output. It is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

Errors in your fiddle:

- You use datatables method call but have only added the bootstrap-table library.
- Ajax is not working in the fiddle, but we can ignore that for now.
- To bind the event also for table rows which will be inserted by datatables, bind it to the table and use `tr` as [selector](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in the `on()` method.
- If you want to `find()` an [element by id](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) you need to use the `#`. But beware that you can't use ids if there are multiple elements, use a [class](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) instead.
- Table cells have no value, so use `text()` instead of `val()`.

Updated function:

```
$("#users").on('click', 'tr', function () {
    alert($(this).find("#pID").text());
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/1517/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var Table = $('#CheckinTable').DataTable( {
 // optional info
});


$('#CheckinTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
  let bookingData = Table.row(this).data();
  // do your staff
 });
```